# View Error CakePHP UploadPack plugin

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP's UploadPlugin (https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack). Storing images goes smooth as documented, the problem kicks in when trying to use the helper to view the images:

**Fatal Error
Error: Call to a member function image() on a non-object**

Code:

```
<?php echo $upload->image($entry['User']['id'], 'User.avatar') ?>
```

The helper is correctly loaded in the controllers. What could caseis issue? thanks

UPDATE:

My helper is included as follows:

```
public $helpers = array('Form', 'UploadPack.Upload');
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the `$helpers` array from your controller. It does seem that the UploadPack object isn't initialised.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it by doing the following:

```
echo $this->upload->image($MODELNAME, 'MODEL.avatar');
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. FYI, you can format code using the `{}` button in the toolbar or by indenting a line with four(4) or more spaces.